# Attribute number 10 exceeds number of columns 0

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

This query returns all the rows(around 850+) from the table successfully:

```
select * from my_db_log
 where date_trunc('day',creation_date) >= to_date('2014-03-05'::text,'yyyy-mm-dd');
```

But when I add the `count(*)` with the same query like below:

```
select count(*) from my_db_log
 where date_trunc('day',creation_date) >= to_date('2014-03-05'::text,'yyyy-mm-dd');
```

Then it returns me:

```
********** Error **********

ERROR: attribute number 10 exceeds number of columns 0
SQL state: XX000
```

FYI: `creation_date` is the 10th column of my table.

Interestingly, when i replace `count(*)` with `count(id)` then it returns me `0` but I have records in my table those meet the condition.

**EDITS:** I tried the `vacuumdb` command over the whole database but still it is not working for me. Here is the verbose output for the `vacuumdb` on this particular table.

```
>vacuumdb --full --analyze -h 192.168.1.10 -p 8888 -U root -W --verbose --table my_db_log my_db
Password:
```

Output:

```
INFO:  vacuuming "public.my_db_log"
INFO:  "my_db_log": found 0 removable, 0 nonremovable row versions in 0 pages
DETAIL:  0 dead row versions cannot be removed yet.
CPU 0.00s/0.00u sec elapsed 0.00 sec.
INFO:  analyzing "public.my_db_log"
INFO:  "my_db_log": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
```

Comment: Could be a corrupt index. Does rebuilding the indexes on that table help?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name re-indexing didn't work. But the problem is gone after doing a dump/restore. May be I had some corrupt filesystem in my db-server!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is broken in your database. Try

```
VACCUM FULL ANALYZE my_db_log;
```

Or, more radically, run from the shell on your db server:

```
vacuumdb --full --analyze my_database
```

[Details in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-vacuumdb.html)

The error message indicate breakage in the system catalog [`pg_attribute`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalog-pg-attribute.html) or one of the associated indices. Before you do anything else, read about [**corruption** in the Postgres Wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Corruption). Be very careful not to lose valuable data.
[Then one other thing to try:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-reindexdb.html)

```
reindexdb --system my_database
```

If nothing helps, to repair your obviously broken DB, you could try to [`pg_dumpall`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-pg-dumpall.html) the whole cluster, drop the cluster, create a new cluster and restore the backup. Also make sure you find out what broke your db. That does not usually happen (never happened to me, yet). Chances are, you are facing serious hardware problems, in which case you need to act soon ...

Comment: the `vacuumdb` didn't work for me. I have updated the question with verbose output. However dumping the table into another db without change does work.

Comment: I don't see any mentioning of 850 *columns* in the question. *"rows(around 850+)*" indicates 850 *rows* to me. But I don't understand how the first query can return 850 rows if vacuum claims the table is empty.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: A right, thanks. I had misread that. Removed the misguided remark.

Comment: Why is the shell command "more radical"? The doc says: "There is no effective difference between vacuuming and analyzing databases via this utility and via other methods for accessing the server."

Comment: @exhuma: Because the second option vacuums the whole db, not just the one table.

Comment: `vacuum` without specifying a table will also do it for the whole DB

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Ah, I see. I missed that difference in your commands :)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter The problem is vanished after doing a dump and restore. Also I had only `2GB` space left on my db server. I have freed few space over there as well. So I want to believe on your guess(corruption or any other filesystem error!) that you already mention earlier.