# date_trunc on timestamp column returns nothing

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have a strange problem when retrieving records from db after comparing a truncated field with `date_trunc()`.

This query doesn't return any data:

```
select id from my_db_log 
 where date_trunc('day',creation_date) >= to_date('2014-03-05'::text,'yyyy-mm-dd');
```

But if I add the column `creation_date` with `id` then it returns data(i.e. `select id, creation_date...`).

I have another column `last_update_date` having same type and when I use that one, still does the same behavior.

```
select id from my_db_log
 where date_trunc('day',last_update_date) >= to_date('2014-03-05'::text,'yyyy-mm-dd');
```

Similar to previous one. it also returns record if I do `id, last_update_date` in my `select`.

Now to dig further, I have added both `creation_date` and `last_updated_date` in my `where` clause and this time it demands to have both of them in my `select` clause to have records(i.e. `select id, creation_date, last_update_date`).

Does anyone encountered the same problem ever? This similar thing works with my other tables which are having this type of columns!

If it helps, here is my table schema:

```
id serial NOT NULL,
creation_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
last_update_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
CONSTRAINT db_log_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
```

I have asked a different question earlier that didn't get any answer. This problem may be related to that one. If you are interested on that one, here is [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22191982/attribute-number-10-exceeds-number-of-columns-0).

**EDITS::** `EXPLAIN (FORMAT XML)` with `select *` returns:

```
<explain xmlns="http://www.postgresql.org/2009/explain">
  <Query>
    <Plan>
      <Node-Type>Result</Node-Type>
      <Startup-Cost>0.00</Startup-Cost>
      <Total-Cost>0.00</Total-Cost>
      <Plan-Rows>1000</Plan-Rows>
      <Plan-Width>658</Plan-Width>
      <Plans>
        <Plan>
          <Node-Type>Result</Node-Type>
          <Parent-Relationship>Outer</Parent-Relationship>
          <Alias>my_db_log</Alias>
          <Startup-Cost>0.00</Startup-Cost>
          <Total-Cost>0.00</Total-Cost>
          <Plan-Rows>1000</Plan-Rows>
          <Plan-Width>658</Plan-Width>
          <Node/s>datanode1</Node/s>
          <Coordinator-quals>(date_trunc('day'::text, creation_date) &gt;= to_date('2014-03-05'::text, 'yyyy-mm-dd'::text))</Coordinator-quals>
        </Plan>
      </Plans>
    </Plan>
  </Query>
</explain>
```

Comment: Show `EXPLAIN` for both queries please.

Comment: @CraigRinger I have added the `EXPLAIN` with the question.

Comment: Intact, unedited `explain` with no arguments please. Need to see if the plans are the same.

Comment: @CraigRinger Previous one was `JSON` and i just removed the `{[` from there. Added `XML` one for `Select *`.

Comment: Ugh, why? What's hard about "no arguments"? Never mind, forget it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### "Impossible" phenomenon

The number of rows returned is *completely* independent of items in the `SELECT` clause. (But see @Craig's comment about SRFs.) Something must be *broken* in your db.
Maybe a broken covering index? When you throw in the additional column, you force Postgres to visit the table itself. Try to re-index:

```
REINDEX TABLE my_db_log;
```

The manual on [`REINDEX`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-reindex.html). Or:

```
VACUUM FULL ANALYZE my_db_log;
```

#### Better query

Either way, use instead:

```
select id from my_db_log 
where creation_date >= '2014-03-05'::date
```

Or:

```
select id from my_db_log 
where creation_date >= '2014-03-05 00:00'::timestamp
```

`'2014-03-05'` is in ISO 8601 format. You can just cast this string literal to `date`. No need for `to_date()`, works with *any* locale. The `date` is coerced to `timestamp [without time zone]` automatically when compared to `creation_date` (being `timestamp [without time zone]`). More details about timestamps in Postgres here:
[Ignoring timezones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

Also, you gain nothing by throwing in `date_trunc()` here. On the contrary, your query will be slower and any plain index on the column cannot be used (potentially making this *much* slower)

Comment: *"The number of rows returned is completely independent of items in the SELECT clause"*. Unless there's a set-returning function in the `SELECT` list, in which case PostgreSQL's bizarre and sometimes insane behaviour about SRFs-in-FROM comes into play. Doesn't seem to be the case here, but worth considering in general.

Comment: @Erwin I tried the `REINDEX` and `VACUUM` that you have suggested but still not working. But you are right somehow something had happened with my DB. However your suggested better query is working and `we owe you a +1` for it.

Comment: @SabujHassan: A complete dump / restore cycle might fix your possibly broken db. Restore to a new db cluster to be sure ...

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter yes the Restore worked. It was a weird issue!