# Cannot create a table due to naming conflict

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-administration

I am trying to create a table in my database and it gives me the following error.

> ```
> ERROR:  type "tbl_last_alert" already exists
> HINT:  A relation has an associated type of the same name, so you must use a name that doesn't conflict with any existing type.
> ```

Then I thought that the table must exist so I ran the following query:

```
select * from pg_tables;
```

But could not find anything. Then I tried:

> ```
> select * from tbl_last_alert;
> ERROR:  relation "tbl_last_alert" does not exist
> ```

Any idea how to sort this?

i am tying to rename the type by

```
ALTER TYPE v4report.tbl_last_alert RENAME TO tbl_last_alert_old;
ERROR:  v4report.tbl_last_alert is a table's row type
HINT:  Use ALTER TABLE instead.
```

and getting the error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Postgres creates a composite (row) type of the same name for every table. That's why the error message mentions "type", not "table". Effectively, a table name cannot conflict with this list from [the manual on `pg_class`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html):

> `r` = ordinary table, `i` = index, `S` = sequence, `t` = TOAST table,
> `v` = view, `m` = materialized view, `c` = composite type, `f` =
> foreign table, `p` = partitioned table, `I` = partitioned index

Bold emphasis mine. Accordingly, you can find any conflicting entry with this query:

```
SELECT n.nspname AS schemaname, c.relname, c.relkind
FROM   pg_class c
JOIN   pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE  relname = 'tbl_last_alert';
```

This covers *all* possible competitors, not just types. Note that the same name *can* exist multiple times in multiple schemas - but not in the same schema.

#### Cure

If you find a conflicting composite type, you can rename or drop it to make way - if you don't need it!

```
DROP TYPE tbl_last_alert;
```

Be sure that the schema of the type is the first match in your search path or schema-qualify the name. I added the schema to the query above. Like:

```
DROP TYPE public.tbl_last_alert;
```

Comment: `drop type v4report.tbl_last_alert;
ERROR:  cache lookup failed for relation 19108 ` getting the error any idea

Comment: ` schemaname | relname | relkind 
------------+---------+---------
(0 rows) `  i am getting this

Comment: @smn_onrocks: I am afraid that something is seriously broken in your db. You might be able to fix it by reindexing your system tables. [Details in this related answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22191982/attribute-number-10-exceeds-number-of-columns-0/22282860#22282860) There may be a hardware problem at the root of this.

Comment: @smn_onrocks Before you do anything else, follow the advice in: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Corruption

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter have tried all your advice but still getting the error.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't drop type, delete it from pg_type:

```
DELETE FROM pg_type where typname~'tbl_last_alert';
```

Answer (score 0):

The error calls it a "type"; you probably have a type with that name somewhere.

Use this in `psql` to find out what anything is:

```
\d tbl_last_alert
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check it in `pg_type` table:

```
select * from pg_type where typname = 'tbl_last_alert'
```

Comment: `select * from pg_type where typname = 'tbl_last_alert';
 tbl_last_alert |        16716 |       10 |     -1 | f        | c       | C           | f              | t            | ,        |    19108 |       0 |    19109 | recor
d_in | record_out | record_recv | record_send | -        | -         | -          | d        | x          | f          | \x1A      |           0 |        -1 |        0 
|            0 |               | 
` After run the query i am getting this now i want to drop the table how to do it

Comment: @smn_onrocks `drop type tbl_last_alert`.

Comment: `drop type v4report.tbl_last_alert;
ERROR:  cache lookup failed for relation 19108 ` getting the error any idea